# How to select random rows from result set in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried both these queries but none of them seem to work: I wish to fetch random rows from result set in oracle

> select * from TABLE_NAME t where t.ent_application_id = 13101192 order
> by Dbms_Random.Random
>
> select * from TABLE_NAME t where t.ent_application_id = 13101192 order
> by Dbms_Random.Value

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT T.COLUMN1, T.COLUMN2, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
FROM TABLE_NAME T 
WHERE T.ENT_APPLICATION_ID = 13101192 
ORDER BY 3
```

Comment: This did not work either :(

Comment: How come? Do you have more records in the T table that have this application ID?

Comment: No there is just one.